# How to read/write a files to a network attached storage Java Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, jcifs

I am currently developing an app in Android studio to write and read test file to a network attached storage. However it is proving difficult to find the write method. I have been trying using jcifs. The network attached storage has needs to logged in to with a username and password.  With jcifs I have been trying using NtlmPasswordAuthentication however I can seem to implement it correctly because everyone time I try to run this method the app just force closes.

Please can someone show how to write and read to a network attached storage that requires a login and password.

Thanks everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed I put this post up and I do have a solution that allows me to read a text file from a Network Attach Storage.
Hope this helps!

```
private String ReadFilefromNAS(String s, String Username, String Password) {
    //s is the filename path on the NAS
    String file = "";
    SmbFile dir;
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, Username, Password);
        dir = new SmbFile(FilePath + s, auth);
        //If your not using auth use the below
        //dir = new SmbFile(FilePath + s);
        InputStream in = dir.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader q= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = q.readLine()) != null) {
            if(i==0){
                file+=line;
            }else {
                file += "\n" + line;
            }
            i+=1;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR",e.toString());
    }
    return file;
}
```